# HHVM FastCGI configuration issues - ProxyPass fails

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, hhvm

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 running on Vagrant. Apache 2.2.22

I have been trying to test my app on hhvm. I configured everything following this: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/fastcgi

After adding fastcgi module part in my vhost config, I started getting 404 not found error. Then I found out I needed to use ProxyPassMatch. After adding ProxyPassMatch line, I started getting 500 Internal Error. My apache log shows this:

```
[warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /index.php. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

All the modules are enabled.

Here is my vhost config:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /opt/myapp/www/
ServerName myapp.demo
ServerAlias myapp.demo

ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/myapp.demo-error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myapp.demo-access_log common
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/opt/myapp/public/$1

<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
                    SetHandler hhvm-php-extension
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch \.hh$>
            SetHandler hhvm-hack-extension
    </FilesMatch>

    Alias /hhvm /hhvm
    Action hhvm-php-extension /hhvm virtual
    Action hhvm-hack-extension /hhvm virtual

    FastCgiExternalServer /hhvm -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 300

</IfModule>
```

Thanks!